# Spring PropertySource is not loaded in tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a spring `@Component` class which is used to load properties from a .properties file in the classpath. The class looks like:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("mail")
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class MailProperties {
    private String user;

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

}
```

I am having a unit test for the above class, but at the unit tests the `user` property is always `null`, meaning it is not loaded from the .properties file. I tried adding the same properties file under test/resources, but without any luck.

Am i doing something wrong here? The test class looks like below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = {MailProperties.class})
public class MailPropertiesTest {

    @Autowired
    private MailProperties mailProperties;

    @Test
    public void testUser() {
        assertNotNull( this.mailProperties.getUser());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `@Value` annotation on the user field.

```
@Value("${key.from.properties.file}")
private String user;
```

You could also attach the annotation to the setter.